# Desktop looks weird as PC wakes after suspension

Tags: suspend

[That's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Cux.png)

Desktop icons have no text but shadows of it. Some parts of GUI still have normal labels but if you hover them with mouse cursor only few letters left.

It happens roughly every 5th time

```
lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev ff)
```

Comment: An old graphics perhaps?

Comment: @CelticWarrior  4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller

Comment: What Ubuntu release/flavor are your running? Couldn't recognized with the desktop alone.

Comment: @CelticWarrior  Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: Your already using the optimal Intel drivers as they are the default. And you have a common DE which usually has no problem with suspension... It points out to hardware but there are a handful of Intel Graphics that have issue in Linux and require additional boot parameters. Please edit your question with the result of `lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'`